# Drupal 6. Content Profile

Tags: drupal-6

I have a problem with creating custom user registration form. I want to place my own form instead of basic with only name, pass and email. I want to add some radios input and select.

I kwon I should use Content Profile module.

I know how to create fields with this module, but I have no idea and I didn't find any tip for take this field to user registration form.

Could anybody help?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is a checkbox on the field properties page that says something like 'add this field to the user registration form'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. Could you tell me exactly where is that combo. I create additional fields in  content types>profiles>manage fields, but I can't find any that kind of input:(

Comment: Click through to edit the field you want to add to the registration page. On that page toward the bottom you will see the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Webform` module in [here](http://drupal.org/project/webform). And if you want to have your new webform in a view then just embed it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I will be answering for the sake of any one running into this again like I did today.

Yes, content profile can be used, where fields should be added to the profile content type. You will also have to enable 'Content Profile User Registration Integration' module, then options will be available under 'content profile' tab in the profile content type page, make sure to check "Use on registration" in "user registration" collapsible field group.

Doing the above won't show the fields in you have enabled "Content permissions" module. Make sure to revise the permissions of the fields you have added and grant view/edit permissions on them to anonymous/authenticated users, and they should be showing fine afterwards.